# Autocomplete Error - Object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am running into an issue. I have my jquery listed like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadList()
{        
    var ds=null;
    ds = <%=listFilter %>;
    $("#<%=mytest.ClientID%>").autocomplete({
        source: ds
    }
        );
}
```

When I run the code, I keep getting the error on line .autocomplete saying that object doesn't support property or method 'autocomplete'
what am I missing??

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <asp:TextBox id="mytest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery UI twice? (It shouldn't be the problem, the second one will just overwrite the first, but...)

Comment: maybe nothing is found by your jquery call $("#mytest").
Remember to do that on DOMContentLoaded event.